# Rhythm combinations in a 16 notes bar.

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations are possible between a note-event and a silence-event (i.e. a played note and a pause) over 16 consecutive beats? In other words, if one musical bar is divided into 16 parts (16th notes) of equal duration, filled with either a sound or a silence, how many combinations of the two are possible within the given structure of 16 events?

I hope this is clear enough...sorry, musician here, therefore almost completely unprepared to approach the question. I am not even sure if I am asking about combinations or permutations.

An example: (1= sound 0= pause) .

1000 0010 0011 0011

1111 0000 0111 1010

Comment: The linked question applies under the musically reasonable condition that multiple adjacent rests are identical to a longer rest, but multiple adjacent notes are not (i.e., two quarter rests are the same as a half rest, but two quarter notes are different from a half note). If that's what you want, then there are $F(2n+1)$ possible $n$-beat sequences, where $F(k)$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number. So in your case there are $F(33)=3524578$ possible 16-beat sequences.

Answer (score 4):

The number of $16$ long sequences of $0$ and $1$ is $2^{16} = 65536$. I think that's what you are asking for.